# Method to find the name most used in an array of hashes rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, hash

I have an array of hashes like so...

```
array = {"id"=>"123", "account"=>"456", "name"=>"CITY"},
        {"id"=>"456", "account"=>"567", "name"=>"CITY DIR DEP"},
        {"id"=>"456", "account"=>"567", "name"=>"BUCK"},
        {"id"=>"456", "account"=>"567", "name"=>"CITY DIR DEP"},
        {"id"=>"456", "account"=>"567", "name"=>"HAPPY"},
        {"id"=>"456", "account"=>"567", "name"=>"CIRCLE"}
```

I need a method to compare the "name" of each item and print the name that has the most duplicates.

Right now I have

```
array.group_by(&:itself).max_by(&:size).first
```

But I need it to compare the names in each hash to complete the method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array.group_by {|h| h['name'] }.max_by {|k, v| v.length }.first
# => "CITY DIR DEP"
```